# How do I fix my cursor working very slow for typing?

Tags: 14.10, cursor, text

I downloaded Ubuntu 14.10 and my cursor works very slow. Even if I type something, the text will appear after 2 minutes on the screen. Please help me out with this problem as soon as possible.

Comment: have you tried disabling the secondary display.

Comment: Is typing text the only thing that's slow? Can you still move your mouse cursor, open menus, etc. at normal speed?

Comment: @Mayur you can change the speed of the cursor going through System Settings-->Mouse & Touchpad and configure pointer speed using scroll bar